# Should device location updates create new Events or update the Managed Object

Tags: cumulocity

I can create a c8y_Position object with a device's location. But should this be a fragment in a new Event, or an update to the device's ManagedObject?

https://cumulocity.com/guides/concepts/domain-model/ shows examples in both ManagedObjects and Events.

https://cumulocity.com/guides/device-sdk/mqtt/ shows SmartREST templates to 'create a new Event' and 'Create location update event with device update' - why duplicate this information?

https://cumulocity.com/guides/users-guide/device-management/#location states 'The Location tab also shows when a device contains c8y_Position property. When you send a new c8y-position event, you can set the same c8y-Position fragment on the device and it will automatically mark its position on the map.' - which suggests that it's only shown if it's a property on the managed object. How would I then see the history of the device's location? Will the location tab not work with Events containing location updates?

Given these are numeric values, why not Measurements? (I may want to graph my altitude, for example - or get a historical list of locations)

Answer (score 1):

There are two different visualisations:

1. The current location (location tab)

   This is based on the c8y_Position fragment in the mangedObject.
2. The location history (tracking tab)

   This is based on events of type c8y_LocationUpdate containing the same c8y_Postion fragment

So basically if you need a history of positions and a relation to time you also need to create the events. If the use case is fine with just latest position you can get away with only updating the fragment in the managedObject.

Why not measurements?

Try to look at it this way: Latitude and Longitude are numerical, correct. But the position is an object because you need both of them. Just having the latitude usually does not make sense.

Having said that there is no harm to save it as a measurement. You just need then your own UI to visualise it.